# I want to printout them in ascending order with the given function code

Tags: c

I really need help for this, like i want to print out them and what do i need to adding to this function to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define nameSizeMax 31
#define listSizeMax 100

char studentList[listSizeMax][nameSizeMax];
int listSize;

void addStudent() {
    if(listSize == listSizeMax) {
        printf("List is full!\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("Enter name of the student: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        char name[nameSizeMax];
        gets(name);
        trim(name);
        strupr(name);
        strcpy(studentList[listSize], name);
        listSize++;
        printf("The new student have been added!\n\n");
    }
}

int searchStd(char list[][nameSizeMax], char item[], int size) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size; i++);
        if (strcmp(list[i], item) == 0) return 1;
        return -1;
}

void removeStudent() {
    int i
    if (listSize == 0) {
        printf("List is empty!\n\n");
     } else {
        printf ("Enter name of the removed student: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        char name[nameSizeMax];
        gets(name);
        trim(name);
        strupr(name);
        int pos = searchStd(studentList, name, listSize);
    }
        if(pos == -1) {
            printf("This student does not exist!\n\n");
    } else {
        for (i=pos; i<listSize-1; i++);
        strcpy(studentList[i], studentList[i+1]);
        printf("This student has been removed from the list: \n\n");
        listSize--;
    } 
}

void fintStudent() {
    int i;
    printf("Enter the name of student you want to search: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    char name[nameSizeMax];
    gets(name);
    trim(name);
    strupr(name);
    int pos = searchStd(studentList, name, listSize);
    if(pos == -1) {
        printf("This student does not exist:\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("\n This is the student list in the order you entered: \n");
        for(i=0; i<listSize; i++) printf("%d - %s\n", i, studentList[i]);
        printf ("This student's postition in the list is: %d\n\n", pos);
    }
    }

void printStudentAsc(char list[][nameSizeMax], int size) {
    int i,j:
        if (listSize == 0) {
        printf("List is empty!\n\n");
     } else {
        char **listP = (char **) calloc(sizeof(char *));
        for (i=o; i<size; i++) listP[i] = list[i];
        for (i=0; i<size-1; i++)
            for(j=i+1; j<size; j++) {
                char *ln1,*ln2;
                ln1= lastname(listP[i]);
                ln2= lastname(listP[j]);
                if (strcmp(ln1, ln2) == 1) {
                    char *tmp = listP[i];
                    listP[i] =listP[j];
                    listP[j] = tmp;
                 }
             }
} 
for (i = 0; i < (*pn); i++)
        {
            nameStr(list[i]);
            printf("Name[%d] : %s \n", i, list[i]);
        }

}

int menu(){
    printf("Menu:\n");
    printf("1- Add a student\n");
    printf("2- Remove a student\n");
    printf("3- Search a student\n");
    printf("4- Print out the student list in ascending order\n");
    int userChoice;
    do{
       printf("Insert ur operation: "); scanf("%d", &userChoice);

    }
}
```

Edited :'( i really struggle about the printAsc like i dont know what to do next . Its really messed me up here. Only the printStudentAsc.

the Menu interface that im not finish yet but i can hanlde this.

Comment: Please define "them".

Comment: Please describe what makes you think that the function does not work as it is.

Comment: Please make an [mre] which allows us to reproduce the observations your describe.

Comment: Why not use `qsort()` to sort the array?

Comment: [dont cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You're not calling `calloc()` correctly. It takes 2 arguments, the number of elements and the element size.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` and `gets()` are both off the map.

Comment: Please double check that the shown code compiles and demonstrates the described observations. I doubt that this compiles `int i,j:`. The immediatly following indentation is a nuisance, please do not undo helpful edits (in this case by Barmar).

Comment: `for(i=0;i<size; i++);` is an "empty loop" due to the semicolon. The following `strcmp` is then executed once only, with an out-of-range value for the index `i`.

Comment: Please delete the question. Compile the shown code with strict warnings. Fix all of them. Edit the shown code accordingly, undelete the question and then give feedback on the comments. Without that, the question lacks a [mre]. If the question is about why it does not compile and how to fix the first compiler error, then it does not lack an MRE but is unclear, because you do not describe the compiler error you are asking about.

Comment: Yes, MSVC reports 12 compilation errors with 5 warnings.

Comment: Do you want me to fix the code for you to something else that works better but you may have to learn it?